# invalid application of ‘sizeof’ and compilation error with struct data

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, sizeof, calloc

I created a data type which I want to send over a socket.
I'm getting a compilation error and a segmentation fault error.
The compilation error I get is `error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct udp_msg_t’` whereas the segmentation fault happens when I do the `memcpy`. What am I doing wrong?

Here is some of my code:

This is the struct I'm concerned about which I defined:

```
typedef struct udp_msg {
    unsigned int udp_eid;
    u_char   udp_prefix;
    unsigned int udp_loc;
} udp_msg_t;
```

In a method I assign the memory and the values:

```
void method(){
    udp_msg_t * udp_msg;

    udp_msg = (struct udp_msg_t * )calloc(1, sizeof(struct udp_msg_t));
    udp_msg->udp_eid = eid.u.prefix4.s_addr;
    udp_msg->udp_prefix = eid.prefixlen;
    udp_msg->udp_loc = loc->rloc.rloc.s_addr;

    send_rloc_udp_to_floodlight(udp_msg);
}
```

And this method actually sends the data over a socket:

```
int send_rloc_udp_to_floodlight(udp_msg_t message) {
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s, i, slen = sizeof(si_other);
    char buffer[9];

    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
        printf("socket");
    }

    memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));

    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(8888);

    if (inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &si_other.sin_addr) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    memcpy(buffer, (char *) message.udp_eid, sizeof(unsigned int));
    memcpy(&buffer[4], (char *) message.udp_prefix, sizeof(char));
    memcpy(&buffer[5], (char *) message.udp_loc, sizeof(unsigned int));

    //send the message
    if (sendto(s, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other,
            slen) == -1) {
        printf("sendto()");
    }

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you forward-declared your struct?

Comment: Is the typedef visible at the line where you use it? If the typedef is in a header, did you include that header?

Comment: the typedef is defined in the same file, so it is visible.

Comment: Unrelated: `if (sendto(s, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other,
            slen) == -1) {` You don't want strlen() here, the buffer is **not a string**, and might have NULs at unexpected places.

Comment: yah forgot about the slen, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not getting the pointer value of the struct field properly. The correct was to do the memcpy is:

```
memcpy(buffer, (char *) &message.udp_eid, sizeof(unsigned int));
```

Answer (score 2):

```c
sizeof(struct udp_msg_t)
```

is incorrect - it should be either

```
sizeof(udp_msg_t)
```

or

```
sizeof(struct udp_msg)
```

Ditto for the cast:

```
(struct udp_msg_t * )
```

in front of the call to `calloc`, although this should just be removed, since it's [redundant and potentially dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?lq=1).

Comment: Once your code compiles cleanly (no errors, no warnings, and make sure you use `gcc -Wall ...`) then if you still get a run-time error it's time to start debugging. See: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Take Paul R's excellent advice. OP you should either use `sizeof(struct struct-name)` or use the name you've typedef'd the struct to have, in this case `udp_msg_t`. The typedef declares a new type called `udp_msg_t` which is equal to `struct udp_msg`. So writing `struct udp_msg_t` will make trouble.